# Bound 2-norm in Julia JuMP

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization, julia-jump

Using Julia's JuMP library, I have a matrix-valued variable `A` on which I would like to impose a 2-norm constraint (equivalently: the spectral / operator norm). However I am not sure how to do this. Below is a minimal-running code of something I would *like* to write

```
using LinearAlgebra
using JuMP
using MathOptInterface
using MosekTools
using Mosek

model = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(
        Mosek.Optimizer,
        "QUIET" => false,
        "INTPNT_CO_TOL_DFEAS" => 1e-9
    ))

maxnorm = 3.0
# We want opnorm(A) <= maxnorm
@variable(model, A[1:4, 1:5])
# @SDconstraint(model, A' * A <= maxnorm^2) # Mathematically valid, but not accepted!

# Make dummy variable and constraint to satisfy
@variable(model, x)
@constraint(model, x >= 10)

@objective(model, Min, x)

optimize!(model)
```

A very overkill way to do this is via

```
@constraint(model, [maxnorm; vec(A)] in SecondOrderCone())
```

as this bounds the Frobenius norm instead --- but this is not preferable. I would greatly appreciate any insights into how this can be done.

Comment: Since Convex.jl does these transformations automatically, I usually just check it’s source code to see how it’s done: https://github.com/jump-dev/Convex.jl/blob/a80853bc69135af70fee38e5d1664f63bbb2d03e/src/atoms/sdp_cone/operatornorm.jl#L61

Comment: Thanks, will try that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MathOptInterface has a cone for the spectral norm:

https://jump.dev/MathOptInterface.jl/v0.9/apireference/#MathOptInterface.NormSpectralCone

```
@constraint(model, [maxnorm; vec(A)] in MOI.NormSpectralCone(4, 5))
```